# Relation between different inner products on space of functions on an interval $[a,b]$.

Tags: functional-analysis, definite-integrals, hilbert-spaces

I was wondering whether we can say something about different inner product spaces of the form:

$L_\omega^2[a,b]= \Big \{f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}: \langle f,  f\rangle_\omega<\infty \Big\}$ where $\omega:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an almost sure positive function (with respect to the Lebesgue measure) such that $\langle 1,1 \rangle_{\omega}$ is finite.

Are there conditions under which we can say for two such "weight" functions, $\omega_1, \omega_2$, that $L_{\omega_1}^2[a,b]\subseteq L_{\omega_2}^2[a,b]$?

This stems from a particular case which I encountered where $[a,b]=[-1,1]$, $\omega_1(x)\equiv 1$ and $\omega_2(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. I was wondering whether every $f\in L^2[-1,1]$ can be written as a generalized Fourier series with respect to an orthonormal basis in $L^2_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}[-1,1]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L_{\omega_1}^2[a,b]\subseteq L_{\omega_2}^2[a,b]$ iff $w_2 \leq C w_1$ almost everywhere for some finite constant $C$. Proof. Using Closed Graph Theorem we can see easily that  the inclusion map is continuous. [You will have to use the fact that convergence in the these norms imply almost sure convergence for a subsequence].  Hence $\|f\|_{L_{\omega_2}^2[a,b]} \leq C \|f\|_{L_{\omega_2}^2[a,b]} $ for some $C$ and for  all $f$  which implies that $w_2 \leq C w_1$ almost everywhere

Comment: So in the case where $\omega:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ and strictly positive there, we know that $L_\omega^2[a,b]\subseteq L^2[a,b]$?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Yes, that is correct.

Comment: And in my particular case $L^2_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}[-1,1]\subsetneq L^2[-1,1]$ ?